# /bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory when running ./byfn.sh -m up Hyperledger fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to blockchain and i was going through the tutorial http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html and doing it. I completed the pre-requisites and download of the samples and binaries. I was able to run `./byfn.sh -m` generate successfully. But when I was running `./byfn.sh -m up` I got the error:

> /bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory

Below is the complete log

```
proceeding ...
Starting peer0.org2.example.com ...
Starting peer0.org1.example.com ...
Starting orderer.example.com ...
Starting peer1.org2.example.com ...
Starting peer0.org2.example.com
Starting peer1.org1.example.com ...
Starting peer0.org1.example.com
Starting orderer.example.com
Starting peer1.org2.example.com
Starting orderer.example.com ... done
cli is up-to-date
/bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory
```

I am running it on windows 7 and on Docker Quick start terminal. Waiting for the help... Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the full path the the fabric-samples directory?  The usual issue here is that you do not clone the fabric-samples repository into a folder shared with Docker Toolbox.  Typically you need to make sure that you clone fabric-samples somewhere under C:\Users on Windows

Comment: Its in the D: drive not in the C drive. D:\BlockChainLearning\fabric-samples

Comment: thanks @GariSingh.. I cloned the fabric-sample to C:\Users\XXXX folder and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 4):

My issue got resolved by following Gari Singh suggestion.

What is the full path the the fabric-samples directory? The usual issue here is that you do not clone the fabric-samples repository into a folder shared with Docker Toolbox. Typically you need to make sure that you clone fabric-samples somewhere under C:\Users on Windows – Gari Singh

Thanks for the help... :)

Comment: I too have the same issue .. I tried copying the fabric-samples folder under C:users/<username>  .. staill does not work .Could you explian the solution in a detailed way please

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all [prerequisites](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html) are installed:

1. Go is installed and `$GOPATH` variable is set.
2. Npm is installed. Run `npm -v` to check.
3. Python is installed. Run `python --version` to check.

If everything looks fine, try to debug which command within `./scripts/script.sh` is failing and fix/install a missing dependency.